# When to use implication and when to use ##delay in system verilog assertions

Tags: system-verilog-assertions

I have scenario of assertion where first a should be high 1 cycle after this b should be high and 1 cycle after that c should be high, after this with 1 cycle delay d should be high
I am confused as to how these assertions should be coded. I have three options please help me which should be followed as correct solution

Option1 : a |=> b |=> c |=> d ;

Option2 : a |=> b ##1 c ##1 d;

Option3 : a ##1 b |=> c ##1 d;

I am getting stuck at these options which one to follow . Please guide me about best solution and as to why

Answer (score 0):

According to me best coding from description would be 
              a |=> b |=> c ##1 d
Reason : Operator used is Non overlapping Implication operator which tells if antecedent is true then evaluate consequent at next clock tick.Use of this operator is needed as b has to be high only if a is high else not necessary.so,condition of a is implying condition of b.so is the case with c.
But in case of d, statement says delay which means to use ## to specify number of clock cycles delay.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 is the only correct option (assuming you want this triggered whenever a is high). Implication is true if the antecedent is false or if the consequent is true.
Option1 : a |=> b |=> c |=> d ; -> If !a, this is true, if a ##1 !b, then this is true, if a ##1 b ##1 !c, then this is true. As soon as the antecedent is false, the whole statement is true.

Basically (b |=> c) is true when b is false, which means Option1 says that if a is high AND if b is high on the next cycle AND if c is high on the next cycle then d must be high on the last cycle. That is not what you need.

Although your question is actually requires a then b then c then d. That would require this:

```
a ##1 b ##1 c ##1 d
```